# Can't return property of a class but can return a local variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `InMemoryDataService` for an Angular application.

The code at first looked like this:

```
createDb() {
  const borders = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Front border' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Potager' },
  ];

  return { borders };
}
```

Which works.

I changed it to:

```
public readonly borders: Border[];

constructor() {
    this.borders = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Front border' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Potager' },
    ];
}

createDb() {
    return { this.borders };
}
```

Which gives the following error:

`':' expected`

In the createDb method. I do not understand the reason for this error.

If I change the code to:

```
createDb() {
    const bordersCopy = this.borders;

    return { bordersCopy };
  }
```

Everything is fine again. But I fail to understand why.

Why can't I return the property but I can return a local variable that's been assigned the property?

Comment: `{ borders: this.borders }`; what you have isn't a valid object shorthand.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wasn't aware I was creating an object. It makes sense though now that you mention it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below format is feature of ES2015 known as [`Property value shorthand`](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/), where if you mention `variable` name inside `{ }` Object parenthesis, it will implicitly creates a property with the same name that assignment variable has.

```
return { borders };
//similar to
//return { borders: borders };
```

Where as other below syntax didn't work because, you directly assigning some value inside `Object` extracted from this.

```
createDb() {
    return { this.borders };
    //interpreted as
    // return { 'borderValue' }; //which is syntactically and semantically wrong.
}
```

---

You could write it as below to solve your problem.

```
createDb() {
    return { borders: this.borders };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I'll go read the page you linked to.